# Side-menu in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to make a same nav-bar like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-menus?file=app%2Fmenu-item%2Fmenu-item.component.html

But only with two levels,kinda like this:

1. Menu

   - submenu1

     - subsubmenu1
   - submenu2
2. Menu2

   - submenu1
   - submenu2

[image]

So when I hovering or clicking on the Menu, the submenu come up withe their sub-menus

I hope you can understand it, and you can help to me, I can't find something like this.

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, i'm edited my answer

Comment: the picture doesn't clarify anything, you already had a link to the example. What are you trying to do that the example doesn't?

Comment: So i don't want a third level, I want to list under the second level

Comment: so remove the third child (app.component.ts)?

Comment: The example provided uses an iterator "items". If you pass only 2 levels, it should work after a little work around sub menu.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component.ts you will find the nav items.

Just remove the childeren and you won't get the third level in your menu.

```
navItems: NavItem[] = [
    {
      displayName: 'AngularMix',
      iconName: 'close',
      children: [
        {
          displayName: 'Speakers',
          iconName: 'group',
          children: [
            {
              displayName: 'Michael Prentice',
              iconName: 'person',
              route: 'michael-prentice',
              children: [
                {
                  displayName: 'Delight your Organization',
                  iconName: 'star_rate',
                  route: 'material-design'
                }
              ]
            },
```

Comment: That's good idea but i want to highlight what is the second and third level, like i make the list in my question, and you can see in the picture

Comment: I removed the children from 'Stephen Fluin' and get this. As you can see, they are both highlighted when hovering over them.
[third level highlight](https://i.imgur.com/BhgK7dC.png)
[second level highlight](https://i.imgur.com/YwMjMZw.png)

Comment: But i don't se the third level under , that's what I want to do

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to realise. If you have a better example of what you are trying, than maybe we can help better.

Comment: So I find better picture, don't watch the expand panel,only the structure,So when you open one menu, you see the submenu, and the submenu's submenus,, like on the pic

Comment: I think you'll need a Tree in [Angular-Material](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-mat-tree) 
If you change some css, than this will look like the one in your example.